# Генерация случайного dataset в python

Tags: python

Как мне сгенерировать случайный датасет для классификации. К примеру 2 признака и выходная метка 1 или 0.

Покажите пример кода плз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В большинстве пакетов для машинного обучения есть учебные наборы данных, в том числе и для классификации. Поиграйтесь с ними. Вот [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/toy_dataset.html) например. А если нужно совсем случайные, то, как вам указали в других ответах - `numpy.random` поможет.

Update:
В `sklearn` есть также метод [make_classification](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html) для создания случайного датасета для классификации с конфигурируемыми характеристиками

Comment: я наверно не правильно выразился в самом вопросе, разумеется тут ничего нельзя классифицировать, т.к. это просто рандом. Просто я один раз видел, как делают синтетические датасеты, где именно данные подчиняются некоторой зависимости (они конечно немного зашумлены), а теперь не могу найти, как это делать. Про рандом, это все понятно. Единственное помню, что через библиотеку sklearn. @CrazyElf

Comment: @КириллМаликов Я вспомнил кое-что, дополнил ответ

Comment: вот это уже полезнее, буду смотреть, спс)

Answer (score 1):

Про учебники я уже замаялся повторять (те, которые надо сначала читать и учить, а потом уже бежать на форум спрашивать про каждую запятую). Но хоть свои вопросы перечитывайте. Если у вас есть датасет, в нем два признака, то метки (хоть 1 и 0, хоть какие угодно) не могут в нем генерироваться случайным образом. Иначе -  чему вы из такого датасета научиться хотите?  Если вам надо нагенерировать просто случайных ноликов и единиц, то опять же это делается элементарно:

```
st=np.random.randint(0,2,10000)
```

Comment: про учебники полностью согласен. Далее по существу. я наверно не правильно выразился в самом вопросе, разумеется тут ничего нельзя классифицировать, т.к. это просто рандом. Просто я один раз видел, как делают синтетические датасеты, где именно данные подчиняются некоторой зависимости (они конечно немного зашумлены), а теперь не могу найти, как это делать. Про рандом, это все понятно. Единственное помню, что через библиотеку sklearn. @passant

Answer (score 1):

вот пример случайного датасета с двумя фичами, интересно что вы тут сможете классифицировать?

```
from numpy import random
import pandas as pd

x = random.randint(0,2, size=(5, 3))
df = pd.DataFrame(x,columns=['red','auto','y'])

>>> df
'''
   red  auto  y
0    0     1  1
1    0     0  1
2    1     0  1
3    1     0  1
4    0     0  0
```

Comment: я наверно не правильно выразился в самом вопросе, разумеется тут ничего нельзя классифицировать, т.к. это просто рандом. Просто я один раз видел, как делают синтетические датасеты, где именно данные подчиняются некоторой зависимости (они конечно немного зашумлены), а теперь не могу найти, как это делать.   Про рандом, это все понятно. Единственное помню, что через библиотеку sklearn. @SergFSM

Comment: @КириллМаликов ну так может вам тогда нужно вот [это](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/sample_generators.html)

Comment: точно, спасибо большое